# makes disaster likely or makes a disaster likely?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

A quote from The Economist:

> But the central government has the fiscal strength both to absorb
>   losses and to stimulate the economy if necessary. That is a luxury few
>   emerging economies have ever had. It makes disaster much less likely.

Can we write instead "It makes A disaster much less likely", since disaster may be both a count and a noncount noun? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write the sentence without or without the article. There is a subtle difference that may or may not be implied by the writer and may or may not be inferred by the reader.

Without the article:

> It makes disaster much less likely

*disaster* refers to a catastrophic set of circumstances that may have developed over a period of time.

With the article:

> It makes a disaster much less likely

*disaster* refers to a single catastrophic occurrence, such as *Black Tuesday*.